# How to get column value from "nested relation" in sql

Tags: sql, join

Not sure of the correct phrasing to use here, but here's the case.
I have 3 tables.

**Employee**

| id | name | department_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jon Doe | 2 |

**Department**

| id | name | office_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Accounting | 3 |

**Office**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | London |

Now, getting the employee with department name is straight forward:

```
select employee.id, employe.name, department.name as department_name, department.office_id 
from employee 
inner join department on employee.department_id = department.id
```

How can i also include the office name in the result?

Comment: Add one more JOIN to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second inner join for the office:

```
select employee.id, employe.name, department.name as department_name, department.office_id, office.name as office_name
from employee 
inner join department on employee.department_id = department.id
Inner join office on office.id = department.office_id
```